# Bootstrap Table action weird if between specific window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap version 2.2.1. I created a webpage with a table in it. The table take the full width of the container (100%). However, between different size of the window, the table react differently.

See the attached pictures to understand my problem.

[image]

Here's the code of the table

```
<table id="item-table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 4%;"></th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 14%;">Product</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 11%;">Source Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 17%;">Source Location</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 7%;">Rental Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 7%;">Consigned Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 11%;">Destination Type</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 17%;">Destination Location</th>
            <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width: 12%;">Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;"><input class="specs-value" type="hidden" name="specs[]" value=""><a class="trigger-remove_item" href="javascript:void();"><i class="icon-adt_trash"></i></a></td>
            <td>
                <select name="model_id[]" class="trigger-model_id span12">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Select a product in the list</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="source_type[]" class="trigger-source_destination_type span12" data-action_type="0"><option value="0">T.B.D.</option><option value="1" selected="selected">Warehouse</option><option value="2">Show</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="source_id[]" class="span12">
                    <option value="2" selected="selected">High Tech Handling</option>
                    <option value="1">Montreal</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="quantity_rental[]" type="text" value="0" class="span12"></td><td><input name="quantity_consigned[]" type="text" value="0" class="span12"></td><td><select name="destination_type[]" class="trigger-source_destination_type span12" data-action_type="1"><option value="0">T.B.D.</option><option value="1" selected="selected">Warehouse</option><option value="2">Show</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="destination_id[]" class="span12">
                    <option value="2" selected="selected">High Tech Handling</option>
                    <option value="1">Montreal</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input name="price[]" type="text" value="0.00" class="span12"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9"><a class="item-add" href="javascript:void();">Add an item to the contract</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span12
```

are not doing anything i guess. Try to remove them and then maybe forcing the table to expand just with `th %` of it.

i would add `span2` or 4 in some smaller number boxes.

made some changes here... try it and tell me if it solves de problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/TWQ4S/3/